# flex datagrid itemRenderer height?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have a datagrid column that I am using an itemRenderer. Something like this

```
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:HBox width="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalGap="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" height="22">
            ...
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

The row heights are fine if the datagrid has any entities. However if there are not entries the rows height is no longer 22. Is there anyway to fix this?

(I have two datagrids beside each other. One is always populated so it has the right height. It looks really bad when the second one is not populated and the rows do not align).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `rowHeight` property of your `DataGrid` to 22 (or whatever value you prefer). Then just set the height of the `HBox` in the `itemRenderer` to 100%.

Comment: @Zenox: I feel that way five or six times a day. Sometimes the answer is so obvious you just can't see it.